# "Object.getOwnPropertyNames" in Angular.js expression doesn't work

Tags: angularjs

I have a property in controller scope which is a object. Let's say it's `$scope.value = {a: 'a', b: 'b'};`.

In the page I would like to retrieve the names of this object so I's using `{{Object.getOwnPropertyNames(value) | json}}`. But I got empty.

If in controller I have `$scope.names = Object.getOwnPropertyNames($scope.value);` and in the page used `{{names | json}}` I got correct result.

You can find the demo in plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/xJKCunEGtiwsNahGIZo3?p=preview

My question is, why this happen? Which functions was not supported in Angular.js expression?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $scope acts like glue between the controller and the view. The binding of AngularJS ( `{{}}` in the view) can only be applied on $scope objects. That's why calling a javascript function in your html won't work.

If you don't want to bind `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` to the scope or want to re-use it, you can use a filter. Filter are used to transform and format your data :

```
app.filter('objectPropery', [function(){
    return function (object) {
        return Object.getOwnPropertyNames(object);
    };  
}]);
```

And use it in your view (html) :

```
  <h1>in expr: {{value | objectProperty | json}}</h1>
```

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/RgEHJCtoijsnLm0BnGCh